# Releasing memory with std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Says I have a class with a standard container:

```
class Library{
    std::vector<Book> books;
public:
    void putOnFire(){
        books.clear();
    }
};
```

The usual way to clear a container is "clear", however most code is not "STL compliant" so many containers (by third parties) may not have a "clear" method. however, If they have move semantics I could just use std::move right?

```
void putOnFire(){
    auto p = std::move(books); //books cleared when p out of scope
}
```

this is to write most generic possible code that works also with something that is not a STL container with a "clear" method.

Comment: If you have a class with a standard container, then the container will have the standard interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` leaves the moved-from object in a valid but unspecified state. In particular it might stay exactly the way it was before, so while this might actually work with your implementation of the stl, it will certainly not work for all third-party containers. (And might break at any point in the future when your implementation of the stl changes due to an update)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend this. First, it obscures the intention. Either use `c.clear` or `c.erase(c.begin(), c.end())`. A container without a way to erase/remove elements is not a proper dynamically sized container. Also your proposed solution depends on the move constructor of the specific container type, which is implementation defined, no memory must be freed.

As a last resort, I'd recommend using `swap` instead of the suggested move.

Comment: Do you consider `std::array<T, N>` to be a container?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good point. Doesn't matter what I think, the standard defines it as a sequence container ; ). I edited the answer, maybe it's slightly better now.

Answer (score 2):

The vector can have its memory released:

```
void putOnFire()
{
    books.clear();
    books.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

If you are working with some container that is not a standard container then you'll have to consult its documentation to see what operations it supports.

Writing code that anticipates a container with an unknown interface is just not possible.